# MySQL timestamp column not updating

Tags: mysql

This is the query returned

```
UPDATE `casts` SET `cast_name` = 'Test Name', `date_of_birth` = '1968-05-10 00:00:00' WHERE `id` =  '148'
```

I've also tried this query

```
UPDATE `casts` SET `cast_name` = 'Test Name', `date_of_birth` = '1968-05-10' WHERE `id` =  '148'
```

For some reason `date_of_birth` is not updating?

`date_of_birth` is timestamp default NULL.

How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
hence you can't give "1968-05-10"  value to  date_of_birth timestamp field.

if you want to store "1968-05-10" then you can use **DATETIME** fields.
DATETIME range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html